# Login error redirecting to wp-login page

Tags: login, wp-login-form

I have a custom login page for a blog.

If the user gets the logins incorrect then its re-directing them to wp-login page, but I'd like the error to be echoed out on the custom login page - is that possible?

I have this code, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
<?php if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { // Display WordPress login form:
 $args = array(
 'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
 'remember' => true,
 );
 wp_login_form( $args );
?>
<?php } ?>
<div class="wp_login_error">
 <?php if( isset( $_GET['login'] ) && $_GET['login'] == 'failed' ) { ?>
  <p>The password you entered is incorrect, Please try again.</p>
 <?php }
 else if( isset( $_GET['login'] ) && $_GET['login'] == 'empty' ) { ?>
  <p>Please enter both username and password.</p>
 <?php } ?>
</div><!--End WP Login Error-->
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to checkout [wp_signon](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/) as that function can provide a [WP_Error](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_error/) object with the appropriate error messages on login failure.. the only drawback is that you will have to create your own form or replace the action url on demand.

A somehow basic login function can be implemented like this:

```php
if (!function_exists('custom_login_function')) {
    /**
     * Attempts to login a user via POST request.
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    function custom_login_function()
    {
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            throw new \Exception(__('User is already logged in.'), 303);
        }

        $fields = array(
            'nonce'         => 'login_nonce',
            'user_login'    => 'log',
            'user_password' => 'pwd',
            'remember'      => 'remember_me'
        );

        if (!wp_verify_nonce($fields['nonce'], $fields['nonce'])) {
            throw new \Exception(__('Invalid nonce.'), 401);
        }

        $credentials = array();
        array_walk($fields, function(&$field, $key) use ($credentials) {
            if (!empty($_POST[$field])) {
                $credentials[$key] = esc_sql($_POST[$field]);
            }
        });

        $login_status = wp_signon($credentials, is_ssl());

        if (is_wp_error($login_status)) {
            throw new \Exception($login_status->get_error_message(), 401);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```php
if (isset($_POST['log'], $_POST['pwd'])) {
    try {
        custom_login_function();

        $redirect = !empty($_POST['redirect_to'] ? $_POST['redirect_to'] : home_url());
        wp_safe_redirect($redirect);

    } catch (\Exception $error) {
        $login_error = $error->getMessage(); 
    }
}
```

`$login_error` will then contain the error message thrown by the function or by Wordpress in case the login failed.

Please notice that the function above also checks for a [nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces). This is not implemented in the Wordpress login form by default but you can add it to your custom form with a simple function call:

```php
<?php wp_nonce_field('login_nonce', 'login_nonce'); ?>
```

That will insert a hidden field with the name "login_nonce".

Best regards.

Comment: To get the nonce from the form i used "if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['login_nonce'], $fields['nonce'])) {" instead of  "if (!wp_verify_nonce($fields['nonce'], $fields['nonce'])) {". Did I miss something?